# Legal X11 load font or not?

Tags: fonts, x11

I'm learning about X11 programming a bit and was messing with XLoadFont a bit. The following code works on one computer but not on another. However, from all the documentation I can find it seems like it's legal. Please let me know if I'm confused about something:

```
// fail.c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Font f;
    Display* disp;
    XFontStruct* f1;

    disp = XOpenDisplay("");

    f = XLoadFont(disp, "*");
    f1 = XQueryFont(disp, f);
    XFreeFont(disp, f1);

    return 0;
}
```

And of course compiled with:

```
gcc -o fail fail.c -lX11
```

If I understand correct, XLoadFont of "*" should just return any font found. However on two of the three computers I've tried it on it fails. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my distro (gentoo) installs some bad fonts.alias files that have the following line at the top:

```
! $Xorg: fonts.alias,v 1.3 2000/08/21 16:42:31 coskrey Exp $
```

This results (I assume) in matching the "!" to the "*" and then trying to load the rest of the line as a font, which is clearly not a font name. Killed this line and everything works now.